# I am having some trouble making a newline in itemize section, unfortunately \newline \parbox \par or \\ is not working

Tags: line-breaking, itemize

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}    

\begin(document) 

\begin{itemize}

\item{\cventry{2007--2011}{7 GCSEs}{Turk Maarif College}{Nicosia/Cyprus}{\textit{A* to B Including Maths, Physics and English/ 4 A'Levels, Physics-A*, Turkish-A*, \newline Biology A*, Maths-A*}}{}}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a *complete* minimal document, not just useless snippets.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please indicate which document class, or which package, defines the macro `\cventry`.

Comment: @Mico: It's `moderncv.cls` and `\cventry` doesn't allow `\par` etc.

Comment: `\item` does not have an mandatory argument

Comment: yes it is  \moderncvstyle{banking}

Comment: @MetinIlke: Please post the complete example, as Gonzalo and Mico asked already. The `\cventry` is wrongly used here

Comment: I hope its better now?

Comment: I believe you're not supposed to use `\cventry` inside an `itemize` environment.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to put `\cventry` inside an `itemize` environment, but the main error is in the order of arguments:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}    

\firstname{Arthur}\familyname{Uthor}
\address{42, Some Street}{Sometown, Somestate}
\mobile{+1-615-555-1212}\email{A.Uthor@mail.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Summary}

\cventry{2007--2011}
  {7 GCSEs}
  {Turk Maarif College}
  {Nicosia/Cyprus}
  {}
  {\textit{A* to B Including Maths, Physics and English/ 4 A'Levels, Physics-A*, 
   Turkish-A*, Biology A*, Maths-A*}}

\end{document}
```

[image]